# Configuring gVim using a given '.vimrc'

Tags: vim

I have customized my Vim editor settings in Linux by modifying the `~/.vimrc` file. That works as required.

Now, I wish to set the same visual configuration in gVim. I tried copying the given `.vimrc` and placing it in `~/.gvimrc` but it didn't help. How can I import the same changes in gVim?

Comment: GVim already sources `~/.vimrc` by default so there's—in theory—nothing to do. Show us your `~/.vimrc` for further debugging.

Comment: But some settings are resetted on the start of the gui, see here [Why do i need both a vimrc and a gvimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/471/why-do-i-need-both-a-vimrc-and-a-gvimrc)

Comment: *Some* settings, yes. Not sure how it applies to the OP's `vimrc` since we haven't seen it, though.

Comment: sorry @romainl, the "but" was not connected to your comment. I fully agree to your statement. Just hoped he can solve it himself with the link

Answer (score 0):

`:help gvimrc` offers very helpful hints:

> The gvimrc file is where GUI-specific startup commands should be placed.  It
>   is always sourced after the |vimrc| file.  If you have one then the $MYGVIMRC
>   environment variable has its name.

- GVIM also reads your `~/.vimrc`; most of the configuration belongs there, and only there.
- Only configuration exclusive to the GUI should be placed in the `~/.gvimrc`. This usually is just `:set guifont=...` and maybe `:winpos` positioning.

If your configuration from `~/.vimrc` isn't used in GVIM, check the `:scriptnames` output for clues. Also, `:help initialization` provides more background.